# How should I properly block outgoing http traffic with iptables

Tags: linux, networking, security, iptables, firewall

I'm experimenting with iptables, and I'm trying to allow all outgoing requests for HTTPS, but to block HTTP.

I have the code below;

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:https
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            

.
```

Apparently this blocks just about every webpage I try to browse, doesn't matter whether it's http://example.com or https://example.com

What do I not get? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to be much more precise about what you mean by "*blocks just about every webpage*", but the way you're not allowing any DNS through suggests that it might be because you've also blocked all name resolution.

Comment: Hi thanks! After I posted this I learned that by adding NEW, to the state line, I could request sites again (resolving the DNS I suppose). But I wonder how to configure rules to force my browser to give a 404 for http connections and not for https. I hope this helps?

Comment: To which `STATE` line?

Comment: Hehe sorry, the one in the OUTPUT chain

Comment: What do you mean by, allow all outgoing HTTPS and block all HTTP?  Is this a client machine?

Comment: Indeed :) I'm sorry I didn't mention this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's nothing wrong with those rules *as far as HTTP and HTTPS* go.  The problem is that you've also blocked DNS resolution, so no client can *resolve* a host in order to try an HTTPS connection thereto.

You have noted that adding `NEW` to the permitted states in line 1 of your `OUTPUT` chain allows DNS resolution - but it also allows everything else, including outbound HTTP; all the return-half packets are then permitted in by rule 1 of your`INPUT` chain.  Instead, revert to the ruleset above and allow DNS explicitly with

```
iptables -I OUTPUT 2 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

That should allow the DNS resolution of hosts to work, but continue to block attempts to connect to them via HTTP.  Note that the `404` you seek is a layer-4 (protocol layer) error, and you can't achieve that with a layer-3 tool like `iptables`.  Instead, outbound HTTP connections will simply time out, whereas HTTPS connections should succeed.

Comment: Hi MadHatter , this is exactly where I was looking for! Many thanks for the patience and help :)